# 'piping' an observable multiple times in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is my situation: I am making an HTTP request by the Angular's httpClient.

In case of error, I want to pipe the observable to catch that error and return a customized error to the subscribers. i.e.:

```js
let observable = null;

if (sourceType === Source.HTTP) {
  observable = this.http.get("url", options);

  observable.pipe(
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      const newError = new Error();
      ...
      return throwError(newError);
    })
  );
}
...
```

But, I also want to set a timeout on the request, so later, I open another pipe:

```
// ... code above...

observable.pipe(timeout(2500));
```

And then, when is executed, the error is not handled by the first pipe, so my question is: Does the second pipe overwrites the first one? In that case I think this shouldn't be called 'pipe'...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't do anything unless you return it or do something with it:

```
observable.pipe(
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      const newError = new Error();
      ...
      return throwError(newError);
    })
  );
```

You are missing equality. I believe that's what you intended as well. Observable is immutable and whatever is returned from pipe you should store it, return it or subscribe to it to make it work.

```
observable = observable.pipe(
    catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      const newError = new Error();
      ...
      return throwError(newError);
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time a `pipe` is called, the new Observable is returned.
The execution order is only matter after you `subscribe` to an observable.
Examples:

```
const firstObservable$ = of(1);

// firstObservable$.subscribe(console.log) -> '1'


const secondObservable$ = firstObservable$.pipe(delay(3000));

// secondObservable$.subscribe(console.log) -> '1' with a delay of 3000


const thirdObservable$ = firstObservable$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(of(3)),
  map(data => data[0] + data[1])
);

// thirdObservable$.subscribe(console.log) -> '4' without the delay


const fourth$ = firstObservable$.pipe(
  map(a => a + 2)
).pipe(
  filter(f => f > 1)
).pipe(
  flatMap(num => this.http.get('url' + num))
);

// fourth$.subscribe(console.log) -> The result of http call to 'url3'
```